# Running PHP as CLI, takes a long time

Tags: command-line, php, performance

Whenever I need something doing, I write a PHP script to do it. I like PHP, it's simple, doesn't need compiling, and I can have a tool written in minutes.

Trouble is, when I try running PHP in the command line, it takes about five seconds to start, then when it's finished it takes another five seconds to exit and go back to the prompt.

This happens no matter what I'm doing with PHP, whether it's running a script or just viewing the help info.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this problem?

Comment: Try using strace to find out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at a similar question on our sister site [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528371/slow-php-command-line-performance-is-this-normal-or-do-i-have-an-install-proble)

Comment: Right on, thank you very much for the pointer. Funny thing is I was considering posting this on SO first, but decided it wasn't programming-related enough ;)